# Find density function of $X + Y$ , where $X, Y$ random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Here's a question:

> Let $(X, Y)$ be random vector that distributes uniformly in the triangle with coordinates: $(0, 0) , (1, 0), (0, 1).$

Question:

> Let $Z = X + Y$. Calculate density function of $Z$.

What is the right way to solve this question?

According to final answer $f_Z(z) = 2z$ but I can't understand why.

Any help will be welcomed!

---

OK here what I've got:

[image]

In order to get $P(X + Y \le z)$ I have integrate over $\Delta (0, z), (z, 0), (0, 0)$, so:

$$\begin{align*}
\int_0^z \int_0^{z-x} f(x, y)\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx
 & =\int_0^z \int_0^{z-x} 2\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx
\\[1ex] & = \int_0^z \bigg[ 2y \bigg]_{y=0}^{z-x} \,\mathrm dx
\\[1ex] & = 2 \int_0^z (z-x)\,\mathrm dx
\\[1ex] & = 2 \bigg(z\cdot \int_{0}^z 1 \,dx - \int_0^z x \, dx \bigg)
\\[1ex] & = 2 \bigg(z \cdot \bigg[ x \bigg]_{x=0}^z - \bigg[ \frac{x^2}{2} \bigg]_{x=0}^z \bigg)
\\[1ex] & = 2 \bigg( z\cdot z -\frac{z^2}{2} \bigg)
\\[1ex] & = 2 \bigg( z^2 - \frac{z^2}{2} \bigg)
\\[1ex] & = 2z^2 - z^2
\\[1ex] & = z^2
\end{align*}$$

Then derivate the probability function and you'll get:

$f_Z(z) = 2z$.

Is my way right?

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent random variables?

Comment: $(X,Y)$ cannot be "normally" distributed on a triangle. Do you mean uniformly?

Comment: @MichaelChirico Yes, I confused, I'm sorry for that

Comment: My OCD forced me to edit the typo, even though 'destiny function' (sic) is kinda cool. :)

Comment: @Deepak: Now I want to define one!

Comment: @BrianTung Go ahead, it is your destiny. :)

Comment: yes, you're right; do you understand the picture yet

Comment: @MichaelChirico Now I do. thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

The random variable point $\langle X,Y\rangle$ is (jointly) uniformly distributed over the triangle, so the probability that it will lie within a subset of that triangle is the proportionate area of that subset.

The triangle is $\{\langle{x,y}\rangle: 0\leq x\wedge 0\leq y\wedge x+y\leq 1\}$.

The constraint $X+Y\leq z$ corresponds to the subset $\{\langle{x , y}\rangle: 0\leq x\wedge 0\leq y\wedge x+y\leq z\}$ ; when $z\in (0;1)$.  This is a smaller triangle.

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(X+Y\leq z) & = \frac{\lvert\{\langle{x,y}\rangle:0\leq x\wedge 0\leq y\wedge x+y\leq z\}\rvert}{\lvert\{\langle{x,y}\rangle:0\leq x\wedge 0\leq y\wedge x+y\leq 1\}\rvert}
 & \text{where } z\in(0;1)
\\[1ex] & = \frac{\lvert \triangle \langle{0,0}\rangle\langle{0,z}\rangle\langle{z,0}\rangle\rvert}{\lvert\triangle \langle{0,0}\rangle\langle{0,1}\rangle\langle{1,0}\rangle\rvert}
\\[1ex]\therefore \mathsf P(Z\leq z) & = z^2 
\end{align}$$

That is the Distribution Function.  The Density Function is thus: $f_Z(z) = 2 z$.

That is all.

Comment: Thank you very much. One question: why is x+y<=1?and why is $P(Z \le z)  = z^2$?

Comment: 1) In the following figure, $x+y=1$ is the equation of red line, and $z$ is always inside the big triangle, thus $z=x+y\leq1$. 2) The areas of small and big triangles are $1/2z^2$ and $1/2$, respectively, and by dividing these values, you may get $z^2$. Am I right @ Graham? :)

Comment: @Billie The line through points $\langle{1,0}\rangle:\langle{0,1}\rangle$ is $x+y=1$.  The other sides lie on the lines $x=0$ and $y=0$.  So the points inside the triangle with those three vertices must validate the inequalities: $x\geq 0, y\geq 0, x+y\leq 1$.  This right-angle triangle has area of $1/2$ ; as its height and base lengths are $1$.  The smaller right-angle triangle has area of $z^2/2$ ; as its height and base lengths are both $z$.  The division of the smaller area by the larger area is thus $z^2$.  This is the probability that $0\leq Z\leq z$ because $Z=X+Y$.

Comment: @Frey yes, just what I was typing.

Comment: I updated the question with my solution. can you check it out please?

Comment: @Billie Yes, that solution works.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

This picture.

Once you understand why I drew this picture, you should be able to solve the problem.

[image: hint]

Comment: I saw this exact picture in the solution, but I couldn't understand why

Comment: extra hint: when you're trying to find the _density_ function of a combination of random variables, it's _almost always_ easier to start by finding the **CDF** of the combination.

Comment: Can you please extend ?

Comment: Draw for me $\{ (x,y) | x+y \leq z \;and \; x,y\geq 0\}$ for some $z<1$. $\mathbb{P} [Z\leq z]$ is the area of this set. (Why is it the area of this set?)

Comment: Well, it's twice the area, isn't it?  Since the area of the permitted space is $1/2$?

Comment: Michael - I'm really sorry but I really don't get the point

Comment: I updated the question with my solution. can you check it out please?

Answer (score 0):

The density of $(X,Y)$ is jointly distributed in the triangle, AND it has a scaling factor of $2$ so that the area adds up to $1$.

So how do you find the distribution of $x+y<z$? it is the area under the triangle as given in Michael's answer. $P(Z<z)=2(z^2/2)$, here the multiplicative term is $2$, beause, every element $(x,y)$ has a height $2$. Then, how do you find the density from the distribution?

Comment: How did you got $2(z^2 / 2)$?

Comment: @Billie it is the area of the triangle given by the points $(0,0)$,  $(0,z)$ and $(z,0)$ multiplied by $2$. Did you understand why we must multiply with $2$?

Comment: I'm sorry but no.

Comment: it's a triangular prism whose volume is base area times height. the base area is that of a 45-45-90 degree triangle: $1/2*z*z$. as to the height, it's the same as the height of the joint density of x and y. since x,y are uniformly distributed, the height must be constant. since the total area must be one, the height must be 2.

Comment: @Billie this is not a good sign. because this is something really basic. any bivariate density has $3$ components $x$ and $y$ shows you where the things happen and $z$ component shows you how much it happens. Namely the value of the density at $(x,y)$,  $f(x,y)$, so $f(x,y)=2$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The odds for $X+Y$ to be $l$ is : proportional to $l$ ( an infinitesimally wide rectangle of length $l$) if $0\le l \le 2$,  and $0$ otherwise.